# What's the advantage of using macro in c?

Tags: c, optimization, macros

Just as the question, What's the advantage of using macro in c?
What do you think is the advantage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a developer use a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760028/why-would-a-developer-use-a-macro)

Comment: hmmm I guess what I am trying to ask is that what's the advantage in terms of compiler optimization? what's the advantage in terms of debugging etc.. the link to that question isn't what i am looking for

Comment: it's just i want to see what people are using macro for... more like people's personal opinion, not rly a question...

Comment: There are all the basic reasons, but where I really appreciate the preprocessor is using it as a code-generator, as in [this DSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371898/how-does-differential-execution-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, I only use macros for very simple flags (conditional compilation and such).

The efficiency of inline expansion has been taken up by the `inline` keyword, constants can be done better with `const`, and lists of values can be done better with `enum`.

Those latter two have the advantage that the symbols are available to the debugger. With preprocessor values, these almost certainly turn into hard-coded values before the compiler proper sees them. Constant variables and enumerations keep the identifier information available, making the debug process a lot easier.